# Can a noun in the possessive case be the antecedent of 'who'?

Tags: grammar

In other words, are sentences like

> *We had a party at Jane's, who is my cousin.*

or

> *He pressed his face up to Kate's, who flattened herself against the wall.*

grammatically correct?

Comment: I consider that It's ok, actually it's the way in which I use 'who'.

Comment: Wasn't there some big flap about just this kind of sentence on the SATs or GREs a few years ago? _Who_'s a relative pronoun in those two Ss, but RelPros don't replace ADJs (the names function as ADJs, not noun phrases) but NPs. They're probably ungrammatical because the ADJs are elided NPs: _Jane's house_ & _Kate's face_. Jane's house ain't your cousin & Kate's face didn't flatten itself against the wall. I'd say that both require a full sentence: _Jane's my cousin_ & _Kate flattened herself against the wall_. But I need a professional linguist to judge their grammaticality. I don't know.

Comment: I completely agree it JARS in my eyes :) - Change face for sister and you will understand it was the sister who flattened herself

Comment: Bill's right. They're ungrammatical because the pronoun refers to the full NP, not just the possessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Bill that, if the phrases were not elided, they would be ungrammatical. However, However, because these sentences do have elision, I would consider them correct, especially since the relative clause is additional information offset by a comma, and not important information vital to the meaning of the sentence. In addition, phrases like these are common, therefore I would argue acceptable.

1. We had a party at Jane's, who is my cousin. - Correct
2. We had a party at Jane's house, who is my cousin. - Incorrect
3. We had a party at Jane's house. Jane is my cousin. - Correct
4. We had a party at Jane's house. She is my cousin. - Grammatically correct, but seems illogically ordered unless spoken with stress on SHE.
5. We had a part at my cousin Jane's house. - Best sentence.

Comment: I found a number of sentences like these in COCA. For example _Her gaze meets Helen's , who, misconstruing the situation, makes an "OK" sign..._ or _We all got new dresses prettier than Princess Elizabeth's , who was going to become queen as my sister married._ Correct or not, they seem to appear even in edited texts.